# How to use Type Script 1.8 in Visual Studio 2017 for legacy project

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017

I have recently installed visual studio 2017 and tried to run my project in it. It is causing TypeScript error. I think VS 2017 is using Typescript 2.1.5 but my application was writted for TypeScript 1.8.

How can I make VS 17 use TypeScript 1.8. I already have VS 2015 and the solution is working fine on it. But I really want to use 2017(without making changes to code)

The odd thing is:
The TypeScript version mentioned in `.csproj` is 1.8

```
<TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.8</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
```

But if I edit the `.csproj` the `TypeScriptToolsVersion` to something else and then back to 1.8, the solution compiles properly. However, after consecutive compiles, the TypeScript resurfaces.

Comment: Please share if you somehow found out the solution.

Comment: will do, if I find any

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Comment: @Mhd sorry, didn't get a chance to try VS2017. still working on VS2015

Comment: @Mhd the answer from Fredrik Claesson works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I noticed the compile errors disappeared when you "force" a downgrade of TypeScript by applying nuget package Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.1.8.11.

That way the solution/project seems to use the package version instead of the built in version.

Comment: Thank you sir, you saved my day! :) Here is a link to the TypeScript 1.8 NuGet-package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild/1.8.11

Comment: You solution works but I also had to [remove default imports](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Configuring-MSBuild-projects-to-use-NuGet) from .csproj file